# A question about sum of supremum

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers, how to prove that $\sup A+\sup B \le \sup(A+B)$? I have no clues about this, so hope somebody can explain it with detail, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving a complete solution, but please for you to learn try to prove that $\sup (A +B) \leq \sup A + \sup B $

## Solution

Notice $A + B = \{ a + b : a \in A \; \; and \; \; b \in B \}$. By definition, then we have $a + b \leq \sup (A + B) $. But this implies

$$ a \leq \sup(A+B) - b \implies \sup(A+B) - b \; \text{is upper bound for set A}$$

$$ \therefore \sup A \leq \sup(A+B) - b \; \; \text{since $\sup A$ is least upper bound }$$

$$ \therefore b \leq \sup(A + B) - \sup A \implies \sup(A + B) - \sup A \; \text{is upper bound for set $B$}$$
Hence

$$ \sup B \leq \sup(A +B) - \sup A \implies \sup A + \sup B \leq \sup(A +B) $$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in A+B$ then there are elements $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ with $x=a+b$. By definition $a\leq\sup A$ and $b\leq\sup B$ leading to $x=a+b\leq\sup A+\sup B$.
This is true for every $x\in A+B$ and consequently $\sup\left(A+B\right)\leq\sup A+\sup B$

Slightly different:

Assume that $\sup\left(A+B\right)>\sup A+\sup B$.
Then $a\in B$ and $b\in B$ exist with $a+b>\sup A+\sup B$. This
however contradicts that $a\leq\sup A$ and $b\leq\sup B$ and we
conclude that the assumption cannot be true.